# magento fishpig get category list in homepage.phtml

Tags: category, third-party-module, wordpress

As per my requirement. i need to display WordPress category list in homepage.phtml    Is it possible or not in this plugin.

If possible then please provide appropriate help.

Just for your reference homepage.phtml file path is 
**Path :-** frontend/base/default/template/wordpress

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get category by placing this code in your template file:

```
<?php 
    $terms = Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/term_collection');
    $terms->addTaxonomyFilter('category');
    foreach($terms as $_terms){
          // do something here
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($_terms); die('ok');
    }
?>
```

[For more see here](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/advanced-custom-coding/)